# Combine/Intersect results from the same SQLite table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, intersection

I have a table of `items`, with the following columns:

```
ID, name
```

And a table of `properties` for these items, with this columns:

```
item, property, value
```

(where `item` is a *foreign key* pointing to IDs in the `items` table - obviously an "item" may have from zero to many different property-value pairs)

What I'm trying to get is:

- ALL the item IDs
- with a specific name
- for which there are one or more (property-value) pairs.

I have managed to get the desired results for ONE property-value, like this:

```sql
SELECT items.id FROM items
INNER JOIN properties ON properties.item=items.id
WHERE items.name='person'
AND properties.property='someproperty' AND properties.value = 'somevalue'
```

And this returns me the IDs for the items that *do* have a property `someproperty` with a value `somevalue`.

If I want to check whether it has ONE OF given pairs, I'd do it like that:

```sql
SELECT items.id FROM items
INNER JOIN properties ON properties.item=items.id
WHERE items.name='person'
AND (
    (properties.property='someproperty' AND properties.value = 'somevalue') OR
    (properties.property='someproperty2' AND properties.value = 'somevalue2')
    ....
)
```

The problem is I want the same but when it satisfies ALL OF given properties (technically not an `OR` but an `AND`).

How do I go about this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `group by` and `having` as follows:

```
SELECT items.id FROM items
INNER JOIN properties ON properties.item=items.id
WHERE items.name='person'
group by items.id  
having count( case when
    (properties.property='someproperty' AND properties.value = 'somevalue') OR
    (properties.property='someproperty2' AND properties.value = 'somevalue2')
     then 1 end ) = 2 -- this number is property value pair from above expression
```